# Error while posting data to AWS Lambda API

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, api, file-upload

I am trying to Upload a file from a webpage to aws lambda api

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="url" method="post">
        <input id="image-file" type="file" />
        <input type="submit" title="submit" />
    </form>
```

And retrieve the same in API using byte[]. This is giving 415 unsupported media type error. Can you please help to fix this?

Comment: Are you using AWS API Gateway? If that's the case I'm not sure whether AWS API Gateway supports multipart/form-data?

Comment: I'm not using AWS Lambda/API Gateway currently, but I found this on their page:  API Gateway now supports binary payloads. Simply define "multipart/form-data" as a binary media type for your API and proxy the payload directly to a Lambda function. From there you can parse the body to get your file content. There should be libraries available to help parse the multipart body ('parse-multipart' in NodeJS for example)

Comment: Thanks @ClaudiuTomescu ..I tried using multipart as well, but no luck. I am using byte[] as data type in receiving api. Is that correct?. Also can you share the link to aws documentation you mentioned.

Comment: here is the root of the doc where it talks about support of binary payloads in API Gateway: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html

Comment: This is the what i am getting in cloudwatch : [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult: Executing HttpStatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 415